# Is it safe using addslashes in php when parameter charset is utf-8?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have read many post talk about addslashes is not safe for SQL injection, 
but they all refer same example  using GBK encoding.
So my question is:
Is it safe using addslashes() to prevent SQL injection in php when parameter charset is utf-8?

Comment: Short answer: no, long answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1207346

Comment: First of all, any reason you want to use addslashes for mysql?

Comment: @Dale, sorry but I still get any help from this article, could you explain in short?

Comment: @YourCommonSense , good question, I just evaluate if it is necessary to do that, because my company has lots of 'addslashes' code, and all UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, there are two questions in one. And so it's better to voice them separately.

For the question

> Is it safe using addslashes() if charset is utf8?

The answer is YES, it is safe.
Taken by itself, with isolated example, addslashes can produce a safe sequence to be used in the SQL string literal if your charset is `utf8`.

However, taken as a protection measure, intended, as it is commonly used, to "process all the input data to make it safe" it is proven to be fatally insecure. Which for the question

> Is it safe using addslashes() to prevent SQL injection

makes it the only answer:

## NO WAY!

Simply because that this honest function has nothing to do with protection from any injections. And never has been.

What you have to understand, is that the **main threat** is coming not from the semi-mythical GBK vulnerability, but entirely from the **misuse of this function.** As it's just not intended to protect you from injections. The topic of protection is much more complex than simple string escaping.

The problem is that there are a [lot of rules to keep in mind](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection#formatting). And there are a lot of points of possible failure.

For these reasons, a simple string escaping just cannot be considered as an all-embracing protection rule.

From this point of view, parametrized queries, although not offering the 100% protection, can be considered a WAY better measure anyway, eliminating three most dangerous threats:

- because numbers also covered, there is no way to inject via numeric literal
- because of complete formatting, a wrongly escaped identifier becomes not a breach but a development stage error.
- because of automated formatting, a human error is eliminated

The above these three reasons I consider enough for changing your approach.

Besides, properly implemented parametrized queries make your code DRAMATICALLY cleaner. Give me your addslashes-based code snippet, and I'll show you how to make it 3-5 times shorter and cleaner.

Comment: What would you recommend for cases where you can't use parameterized queries? Of course I use them everywhere I possibly can, but if you're storing MySQL statements in something like a MySQL dump, then you have to escape it somehow